# Clojure read the content of a lazy-seq ({ })

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, seq

I'm new in Clojure. I have this problems:

I receive this data from a function:

```
({:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address Madrid, Spain})
```

When I ask for the class, I get:

```
> class x
> clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

I need access to **:lat, :lng, :address**, but I don't know how.

Comment: Should the sequence always contain a single value? You can use `(first x)` to get the first map.

Comment: Your data is not valid. I'd expect `({:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address "Madrid, Spain"})`, with a preliminary `'` if you expect to read it.

Comment: Thanks @Lee that is the key to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defn mystery-fn []
  (list {:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address "Madrid, Spain"} )
)

(println :println (mystery-fn))
(prn     :prn     (mystery-fn))

(def a (first (mystery-fn)))
(prn :a a)

(def b (:lat a))
(prn :b b)
```

with output:

```
:reloading (tst.clj.core)
:println ({:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address Madrid, Spain})
:prn ({:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address "Madrid, Spain"})
:a {:lat 40.4167754, :lng -3.7037902, :address "Madrid, Spain"}
:b 40.4167754
```

Notice the difference between `println` and `prn`.  Using `prn`, you get strings displayed with double-quotes which can help a lot when there are embedded spaces.

Also, when you want to label a printed output, it is often easier to use a keyword as the label like `(prn :xyz ...)` instead of `(println "xyz = " ...)`.